# JIB Maven Plugin - JSP files are not being copied to my image

Tags: java, jib

I'm studying Docker and image creation with JIB Maven plugin for Java applications.

- The image is created successfully.
- I create and run a container from the image. Success - the Web app starts fine.
- I try to access the initial page of the Web app (login page). Success.
- But when I do the login, the next JSP (welcome page) is not found (HTTP 404). I suspect that the JSPs from the application are not being copied to the image, hence the error.

Why is that? Is there any additional configuration to put on JIB?

When I run the application from Eclipse, it works just fine.

- The web application was created with Spring Boot and is packaged on JAR.

Here is my JIB config:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>openjdk:alpine</image>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>${project.name}:${project.version}</image>
                </to>
                <container>
                    <mainClass>com.in28minutes.springboot.web.SpringBootFirstWebApplication</mainClass>
                    <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                </container>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>dockerBuild</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```